# How to use local thresholds when converting gray-level images to binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

To convert Gray-level images to binary, a certain threshold value must be found and pixel values ​​larger than this value must be set to 1, and smaller ones to 0. This threshold value is usually determined as a single value for the entire image.

How can I make the image binary by using the global threshold value, and use local thresholds in certain parts of the picture?

Comment: That's called Adaptive Thresholding. See [OpenCV's Python docs for further info](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#image-thresholding)

Comment: If you want global in some places and local in others, then process the image once with global, then process the original again with local so that you have two results. Now create a mask that is black where you want one and white where you want the other. Then use the mask to merge the two previous results.

Comment: I tried to do as you said, but it did not work. More precisely, I don't know how to code this. Can you help me?